# The TOC Blog Aggregator is Offline

Tags: soft-question

I apologise if this is off-topic.

It seems that the domain name has expired. I hope some member(s) of the community here (I am not one) may know who was the administrator/owner of that site. It was quite a useful resource.

Comment: I've emailed Arvind about this. If he says he isn't planning to renew, I'll look into making a new site.

Comment: @GautamKamath, thanks. That would be wonderful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In 2007, Princeton professor Arvind  Narayanan [created](https://arvindn.livejournal.com/77547.html) the TOC Blog Aggregator.

In 2018, [CSTheory.se Moderator](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/badges/97/sheriff) Suresh Venkatasubramanian  ([@SureshVenkat](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/80/suresh-venkat)) stepped down from moderating here, but took over the aggregator:

> Apologies for the downtime this week. This is [@random_walker](https://twitter.com/random_walker?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) handing over the aggregator code (and this Twitter account) to [@geomblog](https://twitter.com/geomblog?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw). Thanks everyone for following and special thanks to [@geomblog](https://twitter.com/geomblog?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) for taking things over.— TCS blog aggregator (@cstheory) [November 23, 2018](https://twitter.com/cstheory/status/1065990444226621441?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Comment: It is up and running again. The new url is http://cstheory-feed.org/